# LinQ Error linq joint type inference failed to call 'join' error

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm quite new to entity framework and I'm trying to use the join clause on two entities as follows.

```
var alertlist = from elogAlert  in yangkeeDBEntity.Yang_Kee_Logistics_Pte_Ltd_ELog_Tablet_Alert
                        where elogAlert.No_ != null
                        join elogAlertDetail in  yangkeeDBEntity. Yang_Kee_Logistics_Pte_Ltd_ELog_Tablet_Alert_Details
                        on elogAlert.No_ == elogAlertDetail.AlertID



                        where elogalertdetail.employee_id == driverid
                        select new
                        {
                            elogalertdetail.employee_id,
                            elogalertdetail.alert_id,
                            elogalertdetail.no_,
                            elogalertdetail.status,
                            elogalertdetail.created_by,
                            elogalertdetail.date_created,



                        };
```

Hi from the above code I'm getting two errors saying

```
'Error  1   The name 'elogAlertDetail' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.' and 'linq joint type inference failed to call 'join' error  '
```

Currently the two tables does not have any data. Ill be happy if anyone can help me with this situation

Comment: Is it possible that `AlertID` and `No_` is two different datatypes?

Comment: well same data types :) Thank you

Comment: Hey dont call me sir :) cheers just gone through your linkedin though and I just moved from Python / MongoDB to .net stuff more like upside down :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cant use `==` when joining with Linq. You need to use `equals`.

Note that it is not the [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) `.Equals(..)` but the [keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713644.aspx)

```
from elogAlert  in yangkeeDBEntity.Yang_Kee_Logistics_Pte_Ltd_ELog_Tablet_Alert
join elogAlertDetail in  yangkeeDBEntity.Yang_Kee_Logistics_Pte_Ltd_ELog_Tablet_Alert_Details

on elogAlert.No_ equals elogAlertDetail.AlertID //this line has equals instead of ==

                        where elogAlert.No_ != null
                        where elogalertdetail.employee_id == driverid
                        select new
                        {
                            elogalertdetail.employee_id,
                            elogalertdetail.alert_id,
                            elogalertdetail.no_,
                            elogalertdetail.status,
                            elogalertdetail.created_by,
                            elogalertdetail.date_created,
                        };
```

Look at the [documentaion](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9) on Linq join

Comment: equals cannot use for int values your answer is not related to here anyway thank you

Comment: @Kalanamith what do you mean? ofcource you use `equals`, infact you *have* to do so when joining with Linq. See the link in the my answer. Also I made a comment to show you where I changed your code

Answer (score 1):

The error you have relates to the order of arguments around the equals operand on join.

The joined table MUST be the RHS of the equals, and the LHS must be in the row you are joining to.

In this instance `yangkeeDBEntity` is not in the `elogAlert` row

CF the example in MSDN

```
from c in categories 
        join p in products on c equals p.Category into ps 
        from p in ps 
        select new { Category = c, p.ProductName };
```

`c` is in the row you are joining from, `p.category` is on the table you are joining to

in addition you also need to use the word `equals` not `==` as mentioned above